# Print 1st line if the given string matches

Tags: linux

I have a file with below lines. All the services with same definition like below. I have print host name and service description if the given string matches with contact_groups

For example: if i give the string contact_groups as  sunil, it should print Service_description and host_name. Any suggestions on this

```
  define service {
  service_description            xvy
  host_name                      abc
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  checkCertificate!443!
  check_interval                 1440
  contact_groups                 sunil 
   retry_interval                 1440
   servicegroups                  def
  }
```

i am using the below cod. But not working

```
awk '/sunil/{nr[NR-4]}; NR in nr' test.cfg
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` processes the lines in order. By the time you do `nr[NR-4]` you have already gone past the line you want to print, so `NR in nr` will never match.

You should save the lines with the prefix you want in variables, and then print them when the contact group matches.

```
awk '$1 == "service_description" {s = $2}
     $1 == "host_name" {h = $2}
     $1 == "contact_groups" && $2 ~/sunil/ { print s, h }' test.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Split file into separate descriptions:

```
$ split -p define test.cfg
```

You'll get file with names `xa*` in the same folder. For example in my test case:

```
define service {
  service_description            xvy
  host_name                      abc
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  checkCertificate!443!
  check_interval                 1440
  contact_groups                 sunil
   retry_interval                 1440
   servicegroups                  def
  }

define service {
  service_description            xvy
  host_name                      abc
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  checkCertificate!443!
  check_interval                 1440
  contact_groups                 sunny
   retry_interval                 1440
   servicegroups                  def
  }

define service {
  service_description            xvy
  host_name                      abc
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  checkCertificate!443!
  check_interval                 1440
  contact_groups                 sunil
   retry_interval                 1440
   servicegroups                  def
  }

define service {
  service_description            xvy
  host_name                      abc
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  checkCertificate!443!
  check_interval                 1440
  contact_groups                 sunny
   retry_interval                 1440
   servicegroups                  def
  }
```

It's got split into chunks:
`xaa` `xab` `xac` `xad`

Next find interesting:

```
$ find ./xa* | while read i; do grep -q -E 'contact_groups.*sunny' $i && grep service_description $i ; done
  service_description            xvy
  service_description            xvy
```

Comment: It depends on a version of a `split` command installed in your system. 
In Linux you may use `csplit test.cfg '/define service/' '{*}'`. Also it produces other filenames, like `xx00`, `xx01`, `xx02` etc